# how to overcome slow image filter in fabricjs?

Tags: fabricjs

I have a check box for applying biur filter on image, but time taken for applying filter is increasing each time when you check or uncheck it.

Do anybody have any idea about it??

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function applyFilter(index, filter) {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    obj.filters[index] = filter;
    obj.applyFilters(function(){
        canvas.renderAll(canvas);
        $('#loader').hide();
    });
  }

  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c'),
      f = fabric.Image.filters;



      var filters = ['grayscale', 'invert', 'remove-white', 'sepia',                          'sepia2', 'brightness', 'noise',
                     'gradient-transparency', 'pixelate', 'blur',                            'sharpen', 'emboss', 'tint', 'multiply', 'blend'];

   $('#blur').on('click', function() {
    $('#loader').show();     
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');   
    applyFilter(9, checked && new f.Convolute({
      matrix: [ 1/5, 1/5, 1/5,
                1/5, 1/5, 1/5,
                1/5, 1/5, 1/5 ]
    }));
  })
})
```

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jugnu_pathak/emeagcnx/1/)
for fiddle.